# Rename a column in dataframe using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, multiple-columns, rename

I would like to rename my columns in dataframe. Though I am using a ready to use simple rename function under dplyr, I get an error message as shown below. Not sure what is the mistake. Can you please help me?

[image]

I have multiple columns but I would like to rename only the 'operator_codes' to 'operator_concept_id' and 'value_codes' to 'value_concept_id'.

```
oper_val_concepts = function(DF){
  DF %>%
    mutate(Symbol = str_extract(.$value,"[^.\\d]*")) -> df_ope
 key <- data.frame(Symbol = c("",">","<","-","****","inv","MOD","seen"),
  operator_codes 
     =c(4172703L,4172704L,4171756L,4172703L,0L,0L,0L,0L),
  value_codes=c(45884084L,45876384L,45881666L,
         45878583L,45884086L,45884086L,45884086L,45884086L)) 
dfm <-merge(x=df_ope,y=key,by="Symbol",all.x = TRUE)
dfm %>%
   rename(operator_concept_id=operator_codes,value_concept_id=value_codes)
   #select (-Symbol)
 }
```

I expect the output dataframe to have the renamed column headings but I get an error message as shown above. Can you please let me know what is the mistake? I can't share the data as it's confidential.

Comment: Does `DF` on which you apply the function contains columns named `operator_codes` and `value_codes` ?

Comment: Try `dplyr::rename`.

Comment: This worked. Thank you @NelsonGon

Comment: @fmarm - Yes, the columns were present. The trick dplyr::rename suggested above worked. Guess there was same function in another package as well

Comment: `colnames(df) <- c("a","b","c")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose df is the name of your data frame containing "operator_codes","value_codes" as columns. You can change these column names to a new names as below:

Rename a data frame column in R:

```r
colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="operator_codes"] <- "operator_concept_id"
colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="value_codes"] <- "value_concept_id"
```

Comment: can help me with this post?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62698244/get-no-of-days-to-prev-and-next-year-using-r