# Get the range and random days within that range using R

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, dplyr, lubridate

I have a data frame like as shown below

```
test_df <- data.frame("subbject_id" = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
                      "date_1" = c("01/01/2003","12/31/2007","12/30/2008","01/02/2007","01/01/2007"))
test_df = test_df %>%
  mutate(date_1 = mdy(date_1), 
         previous_year = floor_date(date_1, 'year'), 
         next_year = ceiling_date(date_1, 'year') - 1, 
         days_to_previous_year = as.integer(date_1 - previous_year), 
         days_to_next_year = as.integer(next_year - date_1),
         rand_days_prev_year = sample.int(days_to_previous_year, 1),
         rand_days_next_year = sample.int(days_to_next_year, 1)) %>%
  select(-previous_year, -next_year)
```

Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62698244/elegant-way-to-get-no-of-days-to-prev-and-next-year-using-r) which helped me with the code to arrive at the part of the solution.

I would like to do two things

a) Get the range of values using `days_to_prev_year` and `days_to_next_year`. Note that `days_to_prev_year` has to have `minus` sign in front of it as shown in ouptut.

b) pick a random value within that range. Please note that if the range is `[0,364]`, I want the random value to be between `[1,364]` **inclusive**. I don't want `0` as a random value. So, I would like to avoid `0` being chosen as a random value. Similarly, if it's `[-11,21]`. I don't want 0 to be chosen here as well but the rand value can be `-11` or `21`.

I tried the below statement but it doesn't work

```
range = paste0("[-",days_to_previous_year,",+",days_to_next_year,"]")
test_df$rand_days = sample.int(test_df$range, 1) # error as non-numeric
```

So, I tried using the below two numeric columns

```
test_df$rand_days_prev_year = sample.int(test_df$days_to_previous_year, 1) # this doesn't work
test_df$rand_days_next_year = sample.int(test_df$days_to_next_year, 1) # but this works
```

I get an error message like as shown below

```
Error in if (useHash) .Internal(sample2(n, size)) else .Internal(sample(n,  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: You want to have minus sign for 0 as well in `range` ?

Comment: No, I don't need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way :

```
library(dplyr)

test_df %>%
  mutate(range = sprintf("%d, %d", -days_to_previous_year, days_to_next_year)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(rand_days = {days = -days_to_previous_year:days_to_next_year;
                      days  = days[days != 0]
                      if(length(days)) sample(days, 1) else NA
                      })

#   subbject_id date_1     days_to_previous_year days_to_next_year range   rand_days
#        <dbl> <date>                     <int>             <int> <chr>       <int>
#1           1 2003-01-01                     0               364 0, 364        206
#2           2 2007-12-31                   364                 0 -364, 0      -220
#3           3 2008-12-30                   364                 1 -364, 1      -274
#4           4 2007-01-02                     1               363 -1, 363       228
#5           5 2007-01-01                     0               364 0, 364         72
```

Comment: But may I check what would happen if the range is `0,0`?

Comment: I guess that would return an error since `days` is empty. What would you like to do for `0,0` ? Return `NA` ?

Comment: May I check what does this line do? `if(length(days)) sample(days, 1) else NA`

Comment: If the length is 0 it goes to `FALSE` part which is `NA` and any number greater than 0 is considered `TRUE`.

Comment: Hi, can help me with this if you have time?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62708660/elegant-way-to-filter-records-based-on-multiple-criteria-using-r