# Elegant way to filter records based on multiple criteria using R

Tags: r, datetime, filter, dplyr, lubridate

I have a data frame like as shown below

```
test_df <- data.frame("subject_id" = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
                      "date_1" = c("01/01/2003", "12/31/2007", "12/30/2008", "12/31/2005",
                                   "01/01/2007", "01/01/2013", "12/31/2008", "03/04/2006", 
                                   "12/31/2009", "01/01/2015", "01/01/2009"))
```

What I would like to do is

1. Arrange the dates in ascending order for each subject (sort asc within groups)
2. Remove date records for each subject based on below criteria (year doesn't matter):

   2a. remove only Dec 31st records if the first record of the subject is Jan 1st ex: subject_id = 1

   2b. remove only Jan 1st records if the first record of the subject is Dec 31st ex: subject_id = 2

   2c. remove only Dec 31st records if the subject has both Dec 31st and Jan 1st in their non-first records (meaning from 2nd record till the end of its records)  ex:subject_id = 3

I was trying the below

```
sorted <- test_df %>% arrange(date_1,group_by = subject_id) #Am I right in sorts the dates within group?
test_df$month = month(test_df$date_1)  #get the month
test_df$day = day(test_df$date_1)  #get the year
filter(test_df, month==12 and day == 31)  # doesn't work here
```

Can you help me with how can I filter out records based on my criteria?

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: what is `group_by=` within `arrange` supposed to be doing? Do you mean `arrange(date_1) %>% group_by(subject_id)`? (And no, arranging is done regardless of group (try `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% arrange(mpg) %>% print(n=99)` and see that there's an `8` in the middle of `6`s).

Comment: Yes, I meant `arrange(date_1) %>% group_by(subject_id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
starting_names <- names(test_df)

test_df %>% 
  mutate(date_1 = lubridate::mdy(date_1)) %>% 
  group_by(subject_id) %>% 
  arrange() %>%
  mutate(
    without_year = format(date_1, "%m-%d"),
    first_date = first(without_year),
    has_both = all(c("01-01", "12-31") %in% tail(without_year, -1))
  ) %>%
  filter(!(first_date == "01-01" & without_year == "12-31")) %>%
  filter(!(first_date == "12-31" & without_year == "01-01")) %>%
  filter(!(first_date != "01-01" & first_date != "12-31" & has_both == TRUE & without_year == "12-31")) %>%
  select(all_of(starting_names)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

gives:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  subject_id date_1    
       <dbl> <date>    
1          1 2003-01-01
2          1 2008-12-30
3          2 2005-12-31
4          2 2008-12-31
5          3 2006-03-04
6          3 2015-01-01
7          3 2009-01-01
```

Comment: May I know why do you get last_date for each subject? because `12-31` could be in middle too based on date order (years could make a difference) like for subject = 1

Comment: Another question on why do we exclude the first record from the dataframe to check for `has_both`?  `all(c("01-01", "12-31") %in% tail(without_year, -1))`

Comment: @The Great because it is month-day of last date in group. I've translated `record = row` if definition of record for you is diffrent then provide that definition.

Comment: IIUC, if you are trying to get the month-day for last date in the group, may I kindly check on how it is used further in code? What are we trying to do with the `last date`?

Comment: @The Great for 1st filtering I need to know month-day of first row in group. Similar for 2nd filtering I need to know last month-day in group. For 3rd filtering i need to know if there are "01-01" and "31-12" as month-day wtihin group (excluding first row).

Comment: Here in the 2nd filter, `filter(!(first_date == "12-31" & without_year == "01-01"))`, I see that you have already used `12-31` right? So we don't really use `last_date` variable here. Have I understood it correctly?

Comment: What I am trying to say is that the `last_date` variable isn't used in code anywhere for further processing. Am I right?

Comment: @The Great Your own 2nd filtering condition says: if first date (without year)  in group is "12-31" remove all rows within group that have date (without year) "01-01". Second filtering is doing just that.

Comment: @The Great you are completely right about that, it seems that I dont use `last_date` at all so it is redundant.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my doubts. Much appreciated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217141/discussion-between-det-and-the-great).

Comment: Try  with `date_1 = lubridate::dmy_hm(date_1)` in first mutate.

Comment: Hi @det - one quick question. When you use `arrange()` in the code, may I know how does it sort by `date_1` column without explicitly mentioning `date_1` in `arrange(date_1)`? Can help me with this please?

Answer (score 2):

You can maybe also try a base solution with a bit of lubridate:

```
library(lubridate)
# put date_1 as date
test_df$date_1 <- lubridate::mdy(test_df$date_1)
# create the field that's going to be the filter
test_df$cntrl <- paste0(month(test_df$date_1),day(test_df$date_1))
```

Now the idea is to split your df in a list by group `subject_id`, then `lapply` a function that filter using your condition:

```
# split as list
listed <- split(test_df, test_df$subject_id)

# order each df: requested and fundamental for the function
listed <- lapply(listed, function(df){df[order(df$date_1),]})

# here the function: it's a nested if else statement on the field
filtering <- function(x){if
                        (head(x,1)$cntrl == "11") { x[x$cntrl != '1231', ] }
                        else if
                        (head(x,1)$cntrl == "1231") { x[x$cntrl != '11', ] }
                        else if
                        ( "11" %in% tail(x,nrow(x)-1)$cntrl & "1231" %in% tail(x,nrow(x)-1)$cntrl) { x[x$cntrl != '1231', ] }
                        else(x)}

# lapply it!
listed  <- lapply(listed, function(x)filtering(x))

# now as a dataframe, removing the useless column:
res <- do.call(rbind, listed)[,-3]

# lastly you can rename the rownames
rownames(res) <- 1:nrow(res)

res
 subject_id     date_1
1          1 2003-01-01
2          1 2008-12-30
3          2 2005-12-31
4          2 2008-12-31
5          3 2006-03-04
6          3 2009-01-01
7          3 2015-01-01
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the prettiest code I've every written, but this works. I assumed the filters were performed in sequence; otherwise, the second and third filters knock out all of subject 2.

```
    test_df %>%
      mutate(date_1 = as.Date(as.character(date_1), format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
      month = as.numeric(format(date_1, "%m")),
      day = as.numeric(format(date_1, "%d"))) %>%
      group_by(subject_id) %>%
      arrange(date_1) %>%
      filter(!(rep(month[1] == 1 & day[1] == 1, n()) & month == 12 & day == 31)) %>%
      filter(!(rep(month[1] == 12 & day[1] == 31, n()) & month == 1 & day == 1)) %>%
      filter(!(rep(sum(month[-1] == 1 & day[-1] == 1) > 0 & sum(month[-1] == 12 & day[-1] == 31) > 0, n()) & month == 12 & day == 31)) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      arrange(subject_id, date_1)

      subject_id date_1     month   day
           <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
    1          1 2003-01-01     1     1
    2          1 2008-12-30    12    30
    3          2 2005-12-31    12    31
    4          2 2008-12-31    12    31
    5          3 2006-03-04     3     4
    6          3 2009-01-01     1     1
    7          3 2015-01-01     1     1
```